# Concise object filter to array of objects

Tags: javascript

I want to filter an objects key/value pairs to an array of objects by value, whats the most concise way to do this?

input data

```
{
    a: 0
    b: 0
    c: 2
    d: 1
}
```

output data based on any value that is not 0

```
[
{name:"c", value:2},
{name:"d", value:1}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a solution using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the object entries.
[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns an array of `[key,value]` pairs i.e `[["a", 0], ["b", 0], ["c", 2], ["d", 1]]` for this example. First I filter out the entries without value `0` after that I map through the result array and return in the format you want

```js
let a = {    a: 0,    b: 0,    c: 2,    d: 1}

let r = Object.entries(a).filter(([k,v]) => v!==0).map(([name,value])=>({name,value}))

console.log(r)
```

and a solution using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
here I'm checking if the value is `0` inside the loop and adding to the accumulator if it is not.
I would recommend `reduce` as it loops through the entries array only once. While in the first it has to loop separately for the `filter` and `map` stages.

```js
let a = {a: 0,b: 0,c: 2,d: 1}

let r = Object.entries(a).reduce((acc,[name,value]) => {
    if(value !==0)acc.push({name,value})
  return acc
},[])

console.log(r)
```

Comment: And they'll be back *after* they copy/paste this correct solution, since nothing is really learned. I'm not criticizing you cmgchess but am pointing out a pattern with the zero-code attempt ppl.

Comment: what exactly were you looking for?

Comment: I'd avoid one-line code when you've not documented how it's used. That's unreadable.

Comment: @Andy in that case should i put a link to the MDN or explain step by step

Comment: Yes. SO isn't just a Q&A site - it's here for people to learn, and, now as a teacher, you have to form your answers so that they are as informative as possible. What does `Object.entries` return? How is `reduce` helpful? Etc.

Comment: @Andy probably wrote my longest answer haha. It is mostly because i'm lazy to write and I'm just following what most people do here

Comment: @cmgchess: good update. Quickly adding an answer is less important than writing a good answer.